# React Native : How to make a sticky SectionList header when it is surrounded by ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I know that `SectionList` sticks its header by default in iOS.
However, when `SectionList` is surrounded by `ScrollView`, no longer sticky header working.

My basic structure is like this.

```
<ScrollView>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>...</Text>
  <SectionList />
</ScrollView>
```

( And live test code is [here](https://snack.expo.io/H1aSPhp8b) )

If I remove `ScrollView` and `Text`, then sticking header works well. But I want to show a Text (or `Image`, `View` whatever) before `SectionList` starts.

Is there a way to solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ListHeaderComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html)

> Rendered at the very beginning of the list. Can be a React Component
>   Class, a render function, or a rendered element.

```
<SectionList 
  ListHeaderComponent={<View><Text>Header</Text></View>}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what exactly I was looking for.